# What is the Sphinx docstring standard for data structure types such as lists?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Does Sphinx have a supported standard for documenting the arguments or return value types that are not a simple, single object?

For instance, in the following, arg1 is a str, arg2 is a list of str, and arg3 is either a str or int. How can you specify collection or composite types in Sphinx? Or is there no common standard for this?

```
def function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    """
    :param arg1: Argument 1
    :type arg1: str
    :param arg2: Argument 2
    :type arg2: list[str]
    :param arg3: Argument 3
    :type arg3: str or int
    """
    pass
```

Comment: There is no common standard - here is one suggestion https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html, also seemingly used in e.g. http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html

Comment: It appears that at the very least, :type arg2: collections.Iterable[str] enables type hinting in Pycharm for Python 2.7. Is there a similar Union type in Python that could work for arg3?

Comment: It seems odd to accept `str or int`, but if that's what it takes that's how I'd write it!

Answer (score 4):

**Python 3.5 type hints**

While not yet supported by Sphinx, will likely make Sphinx type annotations obsolete one day. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

For now, I recommend using the exact same syntax as that module, which will:

- make porting easier, and possibly automatable, later on
- specifies a unique well defined way to do things

Example:

```
def f(list_of_int):
    """
    :type list_of_int: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    return list_of_int[0] + list_of_int[1]
```

Then when you have 3.5, you will write just:

```
def f(list_of_int : List[int]) -> int:
    return list_of_int[0] + list_of_int[1]
```

The `str or int` part can be expressed with `Union`: [How to express multiple types for a single parameter or a return value in docstrings that are processed by Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr/40801906#40801906)

Comment: There's also the [sphinx-autodoc-typehints](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autodoc-typehints/) extension to support them in the mean time.