# How to express multiple types for a single parameter or a return value in docstrings that are processed by Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

Sometimes a function in Python may accept an argument of a flexible type. Or it may return a value of a flexible type. Now I can't remember a good example of such a function right now, therefore I am demonstrating what such a function may look like with a toy example below.

I want to know how to write docstrings for such functions using the Sphinx documentation notation. In the example below, the arguments may be either `str` or `int`. Similarly it may return either `str` or `int`.

I have given an example docstrings (both in the default Sphinx notation as well as the Google notation understood by Sphinx's napoleon extension). I don't know if this is the right way to document the flexible types.

Sphinx default notation:

```
def add(a, b):
    """Add numbers or concatenate strings.

    :param int/str a: String or integer to be added
    :param int/str b: String or integer to be added
    :return: Result
    :rtype: int/str
    """
    pass
```

Sphinx napoleon Google notation:

```
def add2(a, b):
    """Add numbers or concatenate strings.

    Args:
      a (int/str): String or integer to be added
      b (int/str): String or integer to be added

    Returns:
      int/str: Result
    """
    pass
```

What is the right way to express multiple types for parameters or return values in docstrings that are meant to be processed by Sphinx?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33482493/407651

Comment: `def add(a: str or int, b: str or int):` worked for me. Better to define a [typing.TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) for reuse.

Answer (score 81):

**Python 3.10 `|` (pipe, binary or) `Union` type hint syntax sugar**

Once you get access, this will be the way to go, it is sweet:

```
def f(i: int|str) -> int|str:
    if type(i) is str:
        return int(i) + 1
    else:
        return str(i)
```

The PEP: https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/

Documented at: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.Union

> Union type; `Union[X, Y]` is equivalent to `X | Y` and means either `X` or `Y`.

**Python 3.5 `Union` type hints**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

```
from typing import Union

def f(i: Union[int,str]) -> Union[int,str]:
    if type(i) is str:
        return int(i) + 1
    else:
        return str(i)
```

**What to do before you get access to `typing`**

For the poor souls stuck in older Pythons, I recommend using the exact same syntax as that Python 3 module, which will:

- make porting easier, and possibly automatable, later on
- specifies a unique well defined canonical way to do things

Example:

```
def f(i: Union[int,str]) -> Union[int,str]:
    """
    :param i: Description of the parameter
    :type i: Union[int,str]
    :rtype: Union[int,str]
    """
    if type(i) is str:
        return int(i) + 1
    else:
        return str(i)
```

**`or` syntax**

While reading through the docs I found another recommendation, now likely fully obsoleted by `Union` which also just works, but which might work on even older sphinx https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists

> Multiple types in a type field will be linked automatically if separated by the word “or”:
>
> ```
> :type an_arg: int or None
> :vartype a_var: str or int
> :rtype: float or str
> ```

**`typing.Optional`: optional arguments**

As mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr#comment121787313_40801906), [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) is a synonym to `Union[SomeType,None]`, e.g.:

```
from typing import Optional

def maybe_i(i: Optional[int] = None) -> int:
    if i is None:
        return 0
    return i + 1

assert maybe_i() == 0
assert maybe_i(1) == 2
```

However, with the introduction of `|`, perhaps the scales have shifted in favor of `SomeType|None` which both golfs better (5 chars vs 11 chars, if you don't spaces around `|`) and is more explicit:

```
def maybe_i(i: int|None = None) -> int:
    if i is None:
        return 0
    return i + 1

assert maybe_i() == 0
assert maybe_i(1) == 2
```

**Sphinx support**

Sphinx supports both `typing` and `:type x: Union[int,str]` well now. Example:

requirements.txt

```
Sphinx==4.5.0
```

main.py

```
from typing import Optional, Union

class C:
    '''
    My doc for C!
    '''
    pass

class D:
    '''
    My doc for D!
    '''
    pass

def main(i: Union[C, D]) -> Union[C, D]:
    '''
    My doc for main!

    :param i: My doc for i!
    '''
    return C()

def main_docstring(i):
    '''
    My doc for main_docstring!

    :param i: My doc for i!
    :type i: Union[C, D]
    :rtype: Union[C, D]
    '''
    return C()

def main_optional(i: Optional[C]) -> Optional[C]:
    '''
    My doc for main_optional!
    '''
    return None

def main_optional_docstring(i):
    '''
    My doc for main_optional_docstring!

    :param i: My doc for i!
    :type i: Optional[C]
    :rtype: Optional[C]
    '''
    return None
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc' ]
#autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

index.rst

```
.. automodule:: main
    :members:
```

Build with:

```
sphinx-build . out
```

Now:

```
xdg-open out/index.html
```

contains:

[image]

and all type links work just fine. Also note how it automatically uses the nicer pipe notation even if we wrote `Union[]`.

One thing to note is that the types set with `typing` syntax show next to the argument, while those set with `:type:` show on the description.

We can make everything show on the description by uncommenting on `conf.py` as mentioned at [Python 3: Sphinx doesn't show type hints correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071573/python-3-sphinx-doesnt-show-type-hints-correctly)

```
autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

which gives:

[image]

but it would be even better if we could instead do it the other way around and show `:type:` next to the arguments. Anyways, both are acceptable.

**`typing.Protocol`: enter polymorphism**

`Union` is usually a code smell. For small stuff it is OK. But saner APIs will instead use polymorphism when possible: [How to implement virtual methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714136/how-to-implement-virtual-methods-in-python/38717503#38717503)

And now `typing` also offers static polymorphism check with `Protocol`, e.g.:

```
from typing import Protocol

class CanFly(Protocol):
    def fly(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Bird(CanFly):
    def fly(self):
        return 'Bird.fly'

class Bat(CanFly):
    def fly(self):
        return 'Bat.fly'

def send_mail(flyer: CanFly):
    print(flyer.fly())

send_mail(Bird())
send_mail(Bat())
```

So here `send_mail` can take any type that implements `CanFly`, e.g. either `Bird()` or `Bat()`, and we don't need any ugly `if` type checks.

Comment: Can you update your example to include the description of the parameter.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in the case of a return value that may be a single type or `None`, `typing.Optional` is the better, intended, solution. Rather than `from typing import Union` and `Union[int, None]`, for example, one would use `from typing import Optional` and `Optional[int]`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional

Comment: @ChrisLarson with the introduction of `|` as a shortcut for `Union` in Python 3.10 however, I'm more tempted to just `int|None`.