# How to specify different return types in python docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

I'm currently writing documentation for my python package using Sphinx and the autodoc plugin. 
For a function return value I can e.g. write `:returns: int: count` which tells sphinx that there is a return value of type int, named count.

I now got a function which gets me predecessors of items in my database:

```
def get_previous_release(release_id):
    """ Holt Vorgängeritem eines Items mit der ID release_id

        :param release_id: ID des items für das Release
        :type release_id: int

    """

    if not isinstance(release_id, int):
        raise ValueError('get_previous_release expects an Integer value for the parameter release_id')

    try:
        release = my_queries.core.get_by_id(release_id)
    except IndexError:
        raise LookupError('The item with id {} could no be found'.format(release_id))

    if 'Alpha-Release' in release.name:
        release = AlphaRelease(release.key, release.name, release.state)
    elif 'Beta-Release' in release.name:
        release = BetaRelease(release.key, release.name, release.state)
    elif '-Release' in release.name:
        release = VRelease(release.key, release.name, release.state)
    else:
        raise TypeError('The item with the id {} does not contain \'-Release\' in the Summary ' + \
                        'and is therefore not considered a Release')

    previous_release = release.get_predecessor()

    if not previous_release:
        raise LookupError('Could not find a predecessor for item with id {}'.format(release_id))

    return previous_release
```

As you can see, it fetches the original item and either returns an instance of class `AlphaRelease`, `BetaRelease` or `VRelease` depending on the content of the field `name` of the items.

What is best practice to define a return value with various possible types in the docstring?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html):

```
returns, return: Description of the return value.
rtype: Return type. Creates a link if possible.
```

You might also benefit from:

```
raises, raise, except, exception: That (and when) a specific exception is raised.
```

So, as one example:

```
def get_previous_release(release_id):
    """ 
    Holt Vorgängeritem eines Items mit der ID release_id

    :param release_id: ID des items für das Release
    :type release_id: int
    :returns: appropriate release object
    :rtype: AlphaRelease, BetaRelease, or VRelease
    :raises ValueError: if release_id not an int
    :raises LookupError: if given release_id not found
    :raises TypeError: if id doesn't reference release
    """
    ... # your code here
```

Unfortunately there is not a strict or canonical choice in the Sphinx grammar and vocabulary for multiple return types. Often one would state a super-type of all the types that might be returned, if one existed (`GenericRelease` e.g.). But Python is just now, in its mid- to late-Python 3 era, defining a richer type notation. The [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html) defines an evolving new grammar for such types independent of the old Sphinx definitions. If you wished to use this emerging standard, you might try something like:

```
:rtype: Union[AlphaRelease, BetaRelease, VRelease]
```

Comment: I know about the rtype directive. But my question is, how to nicely document various return types. Do I do 'rtype: AlphaRelease, BetaRelease, VRelease' or do I define 3 rtype directives for each of the return types a seperate one?

Comment: Added comments and pointer to new `typing` module and its vocabulary. While it remains very much an evolving animal, it is the new standard. It is there I would look for formalisms to supplement the weaker, older Sphinx generation.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.10 `|` (pipe, binary or) `Union` type hint syntax sugar**

This is going to be the way forward in the future, so clean:

```
def f(i: int | str) -> int | str:
    if type(i) is str:
        return int(i) + 1
    else:
        return str(i)
```

Also is also already fully supported by Sphinx:

[image]

More details at: [How to express multiple types for a single parameter or a return value in docstrings that are processed by Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr/40801906#40801906)