# How to specify multiple return types in a function docstring in Python?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, return-type, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

I am aware of the syntax used to build a docstring for Google style such as:

```
def function_with_types_in_docstring(param1, param2):
    """Example function with types documented in the docstring.

    `PEP 484`_ type annotations are supported. If attribute, parameter, and
    return types are annotated according to `PEP 484`_, they do not need to be
    included in the docstring:

    Args:
        param1 (int): The first parameter.
        param2 (str): The second parameter.

    Returns:
        bool: The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

    """
```

However, what if I have a function that can return multiple types depending on which branch of the code is executed? What would be a proper way to document this?

An example is below. What should be put into the `Returns` part?

```
def foo(x, y):
    """Dummy function.

    Args:
        x (int): integer
        y (int): integer

    Returns:
        list/dict: either list or a dict depending on...

    """
    if x > y:
        return [1, 2, 3]
    if x < y:
        return {1:2}
```

There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr) that shows two different possible return types:

```
def add2(a, b):
    """Add numbers or concatenate strings.

    Args:
      a (int/str): String or integer to be added
      b (int/str): String or integer to be added

    Returns:
      int/str: Result
    """
    pass
```

However, I wonder what would be the best way to provide both types AND description so that Napoleon would support it native and it would also be easy to read the docs.

Is using the `int/str:` `%description%` is the only way to handle multiple return types?

```
    Returns:
      int/str: integer if a > b and a string otherwise
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify different return types in python docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004725/how-to-specify-different-return-types-in-python-docstring)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr

Comment: @MikeScotty, thanks for the link. I've updated my answer to be more specific, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I'm not familiar the Napolean notation, but the answers in both linked questions suggest to use a ``Union`` as type (**not** ``int/str``).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is for Python 3 only, I have to use Python 2 for this. Thanks!

Comment: A function should not return different (=> incompatible) types, so your __real__ problem is not how to document your function but how to fix it instead.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, totally agree with you yet still need to know how to document things for legacy code you have no control over :)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov indeed - and I can feel your pain then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use annotations to specify return types of different type depending of result of function, you can do it this way:

```
from typing import Type, Dict, Optional

def function(self) -> Optional[dict, str]:
    if self.result:
        return self.result
    else:
        return "Empty result"
```

[Here](https://dev.to/dstarner/using-pythons-type-annotations-4cfe) you can find more info

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but I am looking for a way to handle this using docstrings which will be read by sphinx.

Comment: Optional gets a single argument, e.g. float, and it means float or None. After Python 3.10, this can also be written as float | None. (Optional[float] = float | None). Here you need Union.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above but use Union instead. (Optional is used if unsure whether to return the datatype, Union is for the case where one of the two datatypes is sure to be returned.)

```
from typing import Type, Dict, Union

def function(self) -> Union[dict, str]:
    if self.result:
        return self.result
    else:
        return "Empty result"
```

Comment: Should it be `Union` in the above example?

Comment: You import `Union` but use `Optional` which is not imported. This code will cause an error please correct