# python docstring for conditional return

Tags: python, docstring

What is the convention for writing a docstring for a function that conditionally either returns something or a `NoneType`? I see posts that might relate to this using Sphinx but I would like to know what the convention is for the format in the below code:

```
def some_func(input):
    """
    Some docstring

    Parameters
    ----------
    input : float
        Some float

    Returns
    -------
    float
        if condition met: the result
    NoneType
        if condition not met: NoneType
    """
    if input > 0.5:
        return input*100
    else:
        return
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify different return types in python docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004725/how-to-specify-different-return-types-in-python-docstring)

Comment: @Tibebes.M I know nothing about sphinx or the formatting shown in the post, so I was wondering what the general convention was for docstrings as they are written in my post.

Comment: Sphinx (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) is the documentation tool used for most python projects. It generates documentation from your docstrings. Several docstring styles are possible, e.g. the google style (https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html).

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise this. I had never heard of sphinx and was just using spyder which auto-generates docstrings in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single style of docstring; different projects structure them differently, so you should feel free to use whatever works for you if there are no existing examples of how to handle this.

[PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) outlines some general guidelines that should be followed, most saliently

> The docstring for a function or method should summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised, and restrictions on when it can be called (all if applicable). Optional arguments should be indicated. It should be documented whether keyword arguments are part of the interface.

I think what you've written looks fine.

For the record, you don't need the `else` block. Python functions that execute without explicitly returning will return `None`. Additionally, `if` blocks that return don't really need an `else`, because code after them will only be executed if the condition wasn't met.