# Type one of several classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Let's say I have the following two classes:

```
class Literal:
    pass

class Expr:
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, Type:OneOf(Literal, Expr)):
        pass
```

How would I make the type one of the `Expr` or `Literal` class? The full example of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
from enum import Enum
PrimitiveType = Enum('PrimitiveType', ['STRING', 'NUMBER'])

class Array:
    def __init__(self, Type:OneOf[Array,Struct,PrimitiveType]):
        self.type = Type

class Pair:
    def __init__(self, Key:str, Type:OneOf[Array,Struct,PrimitiveType]):
        self.Key = Key
        self.Type = Type

class Struct:
    def __init__(self, tuple[Pair])
```

Comment: What does "How would I make the type one of the Expr or Literal class" mean. Do you want to add an attribute to those classes for a "type" or something? I am unsure what you are asking with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `Union` type:

```
from typing import Union

def __init__(self, Key: str, Type: Union[Array, Struct, PrimitiveType]):

# or in 3.10+

def __init__(self, Key: str, Type: Array | Struct | PrimitiveType):
```

Answer (score 3):

You can refer post:
[How to express multiple types for a single parameter or a return value in docstrings that are processed by Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr)

```
from typing import Union
```

and

```
def __init__(self, Type:Union[Array,Struct,PrimitiveType])
```